# How can I append different items to different lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have just collected the link, title, and the first paragraph of different news articles on [bbc](https://www.bbc.com/), however, I want to add each piece of information into different lists, is there a way I can do that without calling `.append()` on each item.

check out the code.

```
def collect_title_bbc(URL):
    soup=get_html(URL)
    links=[]
    titles=[]
    first_paragraphs=[]
    times=[]
    other_tags=soup.find_all('li',{'class':'media-list__item media-list__item--1'}, limit=3)
    for tag in other_tags:
        title=tag.find('div',{'class':'media__content'}).find('h3').get_text()
        title=title.strip('\n ')
        link=tag.find('div',{'class':'media__content'}).find('a').attrs['href']
        first_paragraph=tag.find('div',{'class':'media__content'}).find('p').get_text()
        first_paragraph=first_paragraph.strip('\n ')
        time=create_time()
        titles.append(title)
        links.append(link)
        first_paragraphs.append(first_paragraph)
        times.append(time)
def create_time():
    dattime=datetime.now()
    tim=dattime.strftime('%H : %M : %S')
    dat=date.today()
    real_date=dat.strftime('%B %d %Y')
    time='Date: '+real_date+' Time: '+tim
    return time
```

Is there a way I can add the different items to the different lists at the same time?

Comment: No.  If you want to change three variables, then you need three appends.  This is why using separate lists is a bad idea.  Why not create ONE list, and store your items as a 3-element tuple?

Comment: @timRoberts that actually makes more sense, thanks, man!